# Opening default android browser with a URL and parameter passing in android

Tags: android, url, browser, url-parameters

I'm trying to pass on a URL of the form:

http://foo.com?param1=somevalue

to the Android Browser, however, once this URL is sent to the browser in this form exactly,

the browser seems to append a forward slash to the URL itself as follows:

http://foo.com/?param1=somevalue

And surprisingly, the android browser is having trouble parsing this. I'm not sure why this breaks the URL.

The invoking code is this:

```
Intent sampleIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sampleURL));
startActivity(sampleIntent);
```

Is this a bug with the Android browser or do I need to do something differently here?

Comment: so u r not geting the url content u r expecting for?

Comment: In the browser address bar I see the second URL with an additional slash. If I remove the '?' only than it seems to work correctly

Comment: @Stacks28 I think this is the same as what I'm doing, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you closely read [How can I open android browser with specified POST parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters) question and the comments, I think you might get an answer. Basically it says that you cannot add extra params to POST to start the browser using Intent, however GET allows that. There is also a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542670/1306419) by @Pete for doing what you wish, inside a `WebView`(if that what you might want to consider):

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("postvariable=value&nextvar=value2", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://www.geenie.nl/AnHeli/mobile/ranking/demo/index.php", post)
```

Hope this helps in someway.

**Update**

Check out [Opening URL on Android web browser causes Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447082/opening-url-on-android-web-browser-causes-google-search) question. It talks about using [URLEncoder.encode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
before passing in the URL. It might help.

Comment: I actually want to close the application itself & only have a page with this url opened. So opening a webview may not be a great solution for me.

Comment: ohhh then need to think :P